# "Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::attendance(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Tags: php, laravel

**I have two table in my database which are user and the attendance table. What I want to do now is I want to show the attendance data from database according to the user in their attendance view which is linked with their profile. This is my attendance function in the userController.**

```
 public function attendance($id)
    {
        $user = UserProfile::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize('modifyUser', $user);

        return view ('user.attendance', ['user'=>$user]);
    }
```

*This is my route to attendance view.*

```
Route::get('/attendance/', ['as' => 'user.attendance', 'uses' => 'UserController@attendance']);
```

*This is my attendance view.*

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1><i class="fa fa-university"></i> Attendance</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Present</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php $no=1; ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->attendance->date}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->attendance->time}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->attendance->present}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

*This is the error that i got.*
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::attendance(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected".
**I am new to laravel.**

Comment: what's your requirement? i am not able tounderstand

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're getting this error because `attendance()` method expects an ID and you don't pass it. Change the route to:

```
Route::get('attendance/{id}', ['as' => 'user.attendance', 'uses' => 'UserController@attendance']);
```

And pass an ID when creating a link to the `attendance()` method:

```
{{ route('user.attendance', ['id' => 1]) }}
```

Or:

```
{{ url('attendance/1') }}
```

If you want to get ID of currently logged in user, do not pass ID. Use `auth()-user()` instead:

```
public function attendance()
{
    $this->authorize('modifyUser', auth()->user());

    return view ('user.attendance');
}
```

Comment: if i logged in with user id two, it can show user id 2's attendance ?
link to attendance view i did like this >> ' <input  type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                    <a href="{{route('user.attendance', $user->id)}}", class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-university pull-left"> Attendance</i></a>'

Comment: @Htoo look at the updated answer. You don't need to pass currently authenticated user ID to the method or to the view. Just use `auth()->user()` to get current user instance and `auth()->id()` to get his ID.

Comment: Mezein, I already edit like you showed me it seems like it works but when i go to attendance view by clicking the button. in the attendance view, it shows, you don't have permission.

Comment: @Htoo that's not related to the issue you've described in your question. It's related to the `modifyUser` policy. So, you need to fix the policy. If you will not be able to do that by yourself, please create another question and post the policy and related code there.